# Get Encryption Status for Volume

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am getting an array of all mounted internal volumes and checking if the volume is encrypted with FV2. Here is the specific code:

```
[url getResourceValue:&volType forKey:NSURLVolumeIsEncryptedKey  error:&error];
    if (volType)
    {
        encrypted = TRUE;
    }
```

The problem is that this code returns true regardless of whether the volume is encrypted or not.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs of NSURLVolumeIsEncryptedKey](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlvolumeisencryptedkey) it looks like `volType` is going to be an NSNumber (a thing that packages primitive values as objects). Use `boolValue` to unpack a BOOL from it.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:NSHomeDirectory()];
NSNumber *volumeType = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
if (![url getResourceValue:&volumeType forKey:NSURLVolumeIsEncryptedKey error:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to get resource value: %@", error);
} else {
    BOOL isEncrypted = [volumeType boolValue];
    NSLog(@"Encrypted: %@", isEncrypted ? @"YES" : @"NO");
}
```

Comment: I added this line;

BOOL isEncrypted = [[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:&volType] boolValue];

and get this error:

ncompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'NSNumber *__strong *' to parameter of type 'unsigned int'

Comment: I don't think the problem is converting it to a bool. Here is the raw value returned of NSURLVolumeIsEncryptedKey: "Printing description of volType:
0"
The value is 0 when the volume is not encrypted AND when the volume is encrypted.

Comment: In your question you have said "code returns true regardless", now you are writing that it is always "0" (inverse). Can you post your code that you use to print it?

In the line above you don't need numberWithUnsignedInt. "volType" is already NSNumber!

Comment: The code is still the same as the original snippet above. 

When I said that the "code returns true regardless" that was in reference to "encrypted = TRUE". The "0" regards the value of volType which is always "0" regardless of the actual encryption status.

Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: If encrypted = TRUE, it means that your check `if (volType)` passes. That means that volType can't be zero.

(I assume `encrypted` is initialized to false in the beginning)

Comment: Your assumption is what I expected also. But the debugger clearly showed that the value was "0". Is this a bug in the framework? I don't know.

Comment: I've added a complete code example. Tell me if it works for you or not.

Comment: Doesn't work. Returns "Encrypted: NO" on systems with FileVault turned on and the disk has finished encryption. As I have said, it appears this value is "0" regardless of the status of FileVault. Maybe this is a bug in the NSURL framework?

Comment: @jbrown94305 This API seems to return wrong results if you have multiple Volumes i.e. you have partitioned your HDD. I've two mac's and one with 3 partitions and one with only one partitions. The above code works fine on mac having one partition.

Answer (score -1):

The API doesn't seems to work properly if there are multiple partitions on a system. I've tested it on 2 macs one with 3 partitions and one with only root(single partition). Following swift code worked fine on system with only root partition(single partition).

```
func checkIfHomeDirIsEncrypted() -> Bool? {
    let url:URL = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory())
    do {
        let resourceValues:URLResourceValues = try url.resourceValues(forKeys: [URLResourceKey.volumeIsEncryptedKey, URLResourceKey.volumeIsRootFileSystemKey])
        if let isEncrypted:Bool = resourceValues.volumeIsEncrypted {
            return isEncrypted
        }
        print("Failed to get status")
        return nil
    }
    catch {
        print("Failed to get resource values")
        return nil
    }
}

if let isEncrypted:Bool = checkIfHomeDirIsEncrypted() {
    print("Volume is \(isEncrypted ? "encrypted":"not encrypted")")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I believe my original code was also failing on single partition Macs but that might be for other reasons. I guess I need to file a bug with Apple?

Comment: Could you please tell why the answer is down vote? A simple down vote doesn't help in improving anything.